# Mapping a dynamic object to typescript function params

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I'm trying to make a list ( example below ) and map it to the parameters of a function.
I imagine the arguments being an object with keys that match the names of the params, and the values being the options for each arg (whether it's required or more important, what type ).

```
interface Command<T> {        // Theese are the parts that I'm curious about, 
  args: T,                    // idk if its even possible, or if there's another solution.
  run(...args: T) {           // 
    
  }
}

const Arguments = {
  name: {
    type: "string",
    required: true,
  },
  duration: {
    type: "number",
    required: false,
  }
};

const cmd: Command<typeof Arguments> = {
  args: Arguments,
  run(name, duration) {
    console.log(`banned ${name} for ${duration ?? "forever"}`);
  }
}
```

If it is possible or you have any ideas of how to achieve this, please let me know as I've been struggling with this for days now .

Comment: You use the word "dynamic" in the title. Is the arguments object known statically or is it given by some external source? For my solution to work the object's structure must be known beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a little more magic to do this. First a type that describes the type of the arguments object:

```
type ArgsObject = Record<string, { type: "string" | "number" | "boolean"; required: boolean }>;
```

Then we'll map strings to their actual types (i.e. "string" to `string`):

```
type MapToType = {
    string: string;
    number: number;
    boolean: boolean;
    // more if needed
};
```

And finally we map over the arguments and get the type for each:

```
type ArgsToContext<Args extends ArgsObject> = {
    [K in keyof Args]: MapToType[Args[K]["type"]] | IsOptional<Args[K]>;
};
```

Where `IsOptional` is defined as:

```
type IsOptional<T extends ArgsObject[string]> = T["required"] extends true ? never : undefined;
```

This is because if it is required, it gives us `never`, and `Type | never` is always `Type`. However if it is not required (optional), it gives us `undefined`, resulting in the desired `Type | undefined`

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwM4HkBGArCBjYUC8UASjgPZwAmAPEsHAJYB2CANFAN5SiQBcUARLQbN+UAD4DGAVwC2aCHFET+aUqQA2EAIaN+AbihwIARyn0jFPqo3bGUAL4A+PQFgAUO+7QAslrAAVUn9waEJ2dyhIqCEmBD4Y5lc3KKhpOQU+NPk4JJTrTR0rNQLGJPskzxCoAElUMGB6UkYtdSp-KAgAD2AIRgokWERUTBxgAG0EhABdRwIofzH+I1NzCAp+KY7u3v6uOCloAH5UiAA3BSg+KT6IADMmNYq3L0HkQIBhJp7uqnhkLZ6fQGf2GWFwszCESiYwA0lAmFAANYQECkW6vJBTPi+AJBEJjEGwqaLLwbTYSWooeqNZqtQkwmZlJ5MHpwW5abDQT4yGQ6agggE7YFDdBg4CzcLJKJaIZ8EG5KL7RgACmwXy6wDlQw+6p+IMcAEo+KdSPQKGV3O41YxaFAZf9IVLIs0ZBA+JKUikvHxBHRYvwWFDPYYTGYLHw6AdA06HNGUhQpHAtA0mu6g57vZJZNkA+mUssw2s+Oz1EgIHGovZo-Y7QNrbQnvW8NgZJYoNzeX0qF40XahhCOOn7Ug+MOK5ElcrOC7y1AE0mU3Z7AbBzGUjP3AB6TfBgB6hzzUXnyZpW53nv36fs7nKQA) showcasing this.

Comment: Thanks so much for the precise response, it works like a char. Here I was thinking I knew how to use typescript. Goes to show you can always learn more (:

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to infer the types of your object as it is, we will make use of the `as const` assertion.

Then we need to create an `ObjectToParams<T>` type alias which allows us to do this transformation and achieves the desired constraint format for the output object assignable

```
const Arguments = {
  name: {
    type: "string",
    required: true,
  },
  duration: {
    type: "number",
    required: false,
  }
} as const;


type ObjectToParams<T extends { [k: string]: { type: string } }> 
= { args: T, run: (args: { [k in keyof T]: T[k]["type"] }) => void }



const cmd: ObjectToParams<typeof Arguments> = {
  args: Arguments, // Get inference for Arguments

  run({name, duration}) {
    console.log(`banned ${name} for ${duration ?? "forever"}`);
  }
}
```

[Code Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggJwOYFcC2BTMUIwLwwDeAsAFAwxgCGmAXEWRRVAJ4AOG9ARNAgJZgkXADSMmCDAEcUfCQBN6UBCgyjyMAL5qKclAipQ%204eiXXN2nGFzDoARhgQixFCdNkYFMAGZUANhFUxDTINGCpcUEgoAG4yONJWDhgAeVsAKwxgKAAVEAAFKn00CAAebJgMAA8oLDlcQhgAbQBrel4BJABdExhEy3bBTU0APhgyAgbCpAh6bOEYZTB6AAopmaIm5pgBGGaMFhAvGGzu45bOxq4%20rk7NAEp8UYA3ED45TXj4yOgYYDRPVIZLK5ApFUp9Q7wZDoLA4UYTMRreiIVCYbAQbQLFBgZaEaiYea6fSGcAaB6mJi-cAQEC%20DAAOl8ICQywABrYqGAwB4YAASPE0DChLwgBB8whEgxGMAwAD8sqsIokTwcXA0rLusXUwVIGiAA)

Comment: This does not solve their problem. `name` should be type `string` while `duration` should be type `number | undefined`.

Comment: Oh got it. I totally missed the gist of the question and what was the desired behaviour. Also your solution does cover that 